# What is wrong with saying "I do not even get the chance of show my skills"?

Tags: grammaticality

> I do not even get the chance of show my skills in an interview.

Someone told me that this sentence is wrong and instead should be:

> I do not get the chance of show my skills in an interview.

Why there is a problem with *even*? I'm remarking the importance of the situation, so I consider the *even* is well used here.

Comment: I don't even get the chance of showing my skills in an interview.
or use to show my skills...

Comment: @Rag, so you have doubts that showing own skill is a problematic thing in general sense or in an interview?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with them. Compare these with their affirmatives: _I (even) got to show my skills in an interview_. Both are correct, as are the initial negatives. The sentences without _even_ mean precisely the same as the ones with _even_, but the ones with _even_ imply in addition that what happened was more (or less, in the case of negatives) than the speaker expected.

Comment: @John,what about *I (even) got of show my skills in an interview.*
 Said the same (.. to show my skills..).

Comment: @Rag, *got of show" is not valid English, but there are some occurrences of it in the Indian English, though.

Comment: @yzT:  I would drop the word "show" and substitute "demonstrate."  Hence, "I did not even get a chance to demonstrate my skills in the interview."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noun chance may be complemented with a *marked infinitive* (that is, *to* + the infinitive form of the verb):

> I don't even get a chance **to show** my skills.

In this case, *chance* means ***opportunity***.

Another collocation is *chance of VERBing*, where *VERBing* is the *-ing* form of a verb. In this case, however, *chance* means ***probability***:

> A flipped coin has a 50% chance **of showing** heads and a 50% chance **of showing** tails.

You may very well encounter the *of VERBing* construction in situations where the *opportunity* sense is intended. This was at one time acceptable, but died out in the last part of the 19th century; today it is again becoming common in informal discourse, and I would not be surprised to see it become accepted in a generation or two.<sup>†</sup> For the present, however, it is **not** accepted in formal discourse.

I recommend that you maintain the distinction strictly in your own writing and speech; the correct uses are perfectly colloquial and will not mark you as pedantic or prim.

---

<sup>†</sup> However, I *would* be surprised to still be around to see it.

Comment: This would have been a good answer to an interesting question that wasn't actually asked, so I'm upvoting it for that alone (I've downvoted *this* question itself, since it's simply concerned with the irrelevant inclusion of *"even"*, in blissful ignorance of even the most rudimentary grammar).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yah, I was tentative; I decided in the end that the title, *What is wrong with this sentence?*, took priority over the third-party answer provided in the body.